# Add Wordpress comment from an external site

Tags: wordpress

I have syndicated a lot of Wordpress blogs and are now showing them on another site. However, I would like the reader to contribute with comments (through the other site). How can I post a comment for a blog post without using the Wordpress form?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using standard WordPress commenting system? You could move your comments to Disqus by using the [Disqus Comment System Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disqus-comment-system/) available for WordPress, then just setup your sites to all run off of the same account?

Comment: Even though the question is two years old, this is still a great suggestion. Thanks! :)